# Sharepoint Online & Angular (latest)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, angular2, forms-7

i've got some questions for whoever has some experience with Angular and SP Online.

**What i'm trying to achieve : Move from SP Designer to custom Angular forms (we all know the limits and bugginess of SP Designer).**

To be more exact i want to be able to attach angular form to a sharepoint list. I want the same functionality that the classic forms offer -> New Item, Edit Item, Delete Item & (if possible) quick edit.

Problem is...i **dont know which version of angular works** for these kinds of things....I've tested AngularJS a while ago to create a new item on a sharepoint list, but angularjs is rather old and i wanna try the latest version.

**My Angular experience is literally 0** so i want to know WHAT (version that works with what im trying to achieve) i should start learning.

**Is this doable with angular 6? 
Does anyone have a tutorial/blog/information center regarding this?**

I've googled a lot since yesterday, but most of the things that ive found were either on older angular version or projects on client side webparts (as i said, **i dont want a webpart**, **i want forms**).

I hope you can help me out with some information/resources. Thanks in advance.

P.S: i've read something about **Angular Elements** but since ive got no experience with angular (yet) i dont really know if its what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how far you can get with Angular forms but in general Sahil Maliks templates work like a charm for me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OgEqWtouuU
https://winsmarts.com/use-spfx-with-angular-cli-3747c306244b
https://github.com/maliksahil/SPFxAngularCLI

Angular is a HUGE framework. I learned it here: https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/learn/v4/overview. It took me weeks.

Comment: I've got access to pluralsight for Angular and im not looking to learn it instantly anyway. I was just searching for something that shows an example so pretty much what you gave me there. 

Many thanks!